# When to use Genitive in comparatives?

Tags: грамматика

So we can use either Genitive or чем when making comparisons. My question is, when should I prefer one over the other?

Я круче его. 
Я круче, чем он.

Я знаю это лучше тебя.
Я знаю это лучше, чем ты.

Она красивее той девушкой.
Она более Красивая, чем та девушка.

What are some general rules?)) Or your opinions?

Comment: Мы более привлекательные тех девушек--we don't say so, and it isn't only a form( привлекательнее) but the choice of the adjective , симпатичнее, красивее, лучше...

Comment: ok, so I'll change the adjective.

Comment: Той девушки is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A comparison can be expressed either with genitive case, or with the conjunction чем  meaning "than" with no difference in meaning :

> Сестра красивее брата. Сестра красивее, чем брат.

In spoken Russian I prefer a short form when possible, but both are widely used.I said "when possible" because if I use менее +adjective, I say чем.

With the **compound** form (более,менее + adjective), the variant with **чем**  should be used, you can't use genitive in this case:

> Они – двойняшки, но сестра более активная, **чем** брат.

The construction with **чем** should be used with parts of speech which are **not declined** or **with prepositions**:

> Сегодня день теплее, **чем** вчера.
>   Мороженое с клубникой вкуснее, **чем** с вишней.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule and no difference. You can use both as you like.

Comment: But Russians obviously have a preference. No? I mean textbooks say that genitive is preferred in speech, but is that true, and for which adjectives and situations?

Answer (score 1):

Они – двойняшки, но сестра более активная, чем брат.
Они – двойняшки, но сестра активнее брата.

Both make perfect sence. There is no difference.

Сегодня день теплее, чем вчера. Мороженое с клубникой вкуснее, чем с вишней.
Сегодня день теплее вчерашнего. Мороженое с клубникой вкуснее вишневого.

You should really use the one you prefer.